# Saving the Edited Data from Datatable in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsf

I am making a JSf web page, to show data of a table, and Edit, Update, Delete that data into the database.

I am using a datatable, the update method in the loginBean class is

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean" , eager=true)
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String emailid;
    private String password;
    boolean disabled = true;


    @EJB
    LoginManagerRemote loginmanager;
    EntityManager em;

    List<Login> list=null;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {System.out.println(">>>> In List  method <<<<");
        list = new  ArrayList<Login>();
        list = loginmanager.findAll();
    }

    public List<Login> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }
public void setList(List<Login> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

     public String updateAction(Login list) {

     System.out.println(">>>> Started in the list for loop <<<<"); 
     loginmanager.update(list);  
     System.out.println(">>>> Update nethod, ersisted data <<<<"); 
     setEditable(false); 
         return "";
 }
```

The Update method in Login manager class is:

```
@Override
    public String update(Login list){
          // String query = "update employee set firstName = ?,lastName = ? where id = 1";
         try{  
         //Query q = em.createQuery("update Login set UName = ?1,emailAdd = ?2, pword= ?3 where id = 1");

        //   q.setParameter(1,this.UName);
        //   q.setString(2,this.emailAdd); 
        //   q.setString(3,this.pword);
           list.getUName();
           list.getPword();
           list.getEmailAdd();
             em.persist(list);
           System.out.println(">>>>> I m in login manager update method, and i have persisted data <<"); 
           return "Users.xhtml";
           }catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(">>>>> The problem during update is <<" + e.getMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
               return null;
           }
         }
```

This method gives error on the id. Duplicate entry for key 1.
In an update method, how can i tell to update entries according to the id, and not to  update the id.

Comment: If everything except saving the list of data/rows into the database is fine, then it involves another layer (the service layer involving EJBs) that is not covered in the current question. You may want to include that stuff removing all of these JSF noise. FYI : `eager=true` is only applicable to application scoped JSF managed beans (those decorated by `@ApplicationScoped` from the `javax.faces.bean` package). It is as good as it is removed from the `@ManagedBean` annotation.

Comment: @Tiny I have updated my question, and included the session class. Now can u please help me

Comment: @Tiny ok, i have done it. replacing em.persist() with em.merge() do it.